# splines ns() identifiability

Tags: r, splines

I would like to understand what are the identifiability constraints implemented by `ns()` in R. I know that common approaches are dropping intercept or some summation constraints (for example thin plate regression splines in mgcv). However, if I am right, there is no constant term among B-spline basis functions used for creation of natural cubic spline basis in R.

Also I would like to know why model

```
Y ~ x:z + ns(x, df=3)
```

where x, z are continuous predictors seems to be unidentifiable unless one degree of freedom is dropped from spline representation (NA coefficient).